# Google Analytics gtag.js Manually adding the linker cross-domain parameter to URLs

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

For the gtag.js implementation of Google Analytics wanting to manually add the linker parameter to specific URLs so that the _ga parameter is present on the clicked URL however it seems that the documentation at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain doesn't currently detail the manual method unless I've misunderstood the document? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after `gtag` is inited you can do it like this:

```
gtag('config', analyticsId, ...)
...

var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
var linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
var destinationLink = linker.decorate(myLinkToDecorate);
```

`ga` is the analytics instance created by `gtag`

Comment: This works for me but it's worth noting that linker.decorate() doesn't return any value

Answer (score 0):

the easiest trick to do that would be to initiate the dummy analytics.js tracker ( with only `ga('create'..)` command and no `ga('send'...)`) with linker plugin enabled and then utilize the `linker:decorate` command over the selected links. Details are described here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#manually_adding_linker_parameters