# Manually generate GA linker parameter with gtag (GA4)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

### Background

To pass a client_id from one domain to another, Google supports adding a "linker" parameter to outgoing Links that are part of the cross-domain tracking setup. This linker parameter contains the `client_id`, `session_id` (I believe, information about Google Ads, e.g. `gclid`) and a basic fingerprint + timestamp. On the receiving domain, if the browser fingerprint matches and the timestamp is not too far in the past, the passed `client_id` and `session_id` are stored in a first party cookie on the 2nd domain and consequently used.

### analytics.js / GA-UA

With `analytics.js` (GA-UA) you could easily do the following, to decorate URLs manually:

```js
function decorateUrl(urlString) {
  var ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']];
  var tracker;
  if (ga && typeof ga.getAll === 'function') {
    tracker = ga.getAll()[0]; // Uses the first tracker created on the page
    urlString = (new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker)).decorate(urlString);
  }
  return urlString;
}
```

Yet, when only gtag is loaded, `window.ga` and `window.gaplugins` are not defined. As far as I see, there is currently no documented way to manually generate links with the linker parameter with gtag.

In Google's documentation, they suggest setting up the linker manually. (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup)
But this has several disadvantages, e.g. I have to create a custom "fingerprint" logic (so that decorated URLs are not shared) and e.g. Google Ads information is not included.
Either way, I would like to use the internal gtag logic to decorate URLs.

### "Hacky" Workaround Solution

gtag automatically decorates `a` tags (as soon as they're clicked) that lead to a cross-domain-tracking domain specified in the GA4 data stream settings (e.g. "test.com"), but I specifically need to decorate URLs manually (i.e. without immediately redirecting to them).
I thought about doing the following:

1. Create a dummy, hidden `a` tag with the URL to decorate
2. Prevent redirection with `onclick='event.preventDefault();'`
3. Simulate click on hidden element so that gtag automatically adds the linker url parameter to the href attribute
4. Extract new href attribute
5. Remove hidden element

```js
function decorateUrlGtag(urlString) {
  var tempAnchorEl = document.createElement("a");
  tempAnchorEl.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  tempAnchorEl.setAttribute("href", urlString);
  tempAnchorEl.setAttribute("onclick", "event.preventDefault(); return false");
  document.body.appendChild(tempAnchorEl);
  tempAnchorEl.click();
  var urlWithLinker = tempAnchorEl.href;
  tempAnchorEl.remove();
  return urlWithLinker;
}
```

This also does not work, because gtag does not seem to register the `tempAnchorEl.click();` call. If I click the link manually, the URL is decorated - as expected.

### Suggested Solutions

The solutions outlined here ([Google Analytics gtag.js Manually adding the linker cross-domain parameter to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388233/google-analytics-gtag-js-manually-adding-the-linker-cross-domain-parameter-to-ur)) also do not work for me:

1. Answer: Even after gtag is initiated, I do not see a global ga element
2. Answer: Same problem (no `ga` defined)

Do you (1) know if there is a way to generate the linker parameter manually with gtag that I have overlooked, (2) know how to make my "hacky" solution work or (3) have another possible solution?

Comment: Hi
same problem for me, I tried the solution explained here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388233/google-analytics-gtag-js-manually-adding-the-linker-cross-domain-parameter-to-ur but I do not see a global ga element :(

Comment: @jswrr I did find a solution today that satisfies #2 

Comment: @Rémy if you still need GA4 manual link decoration, I added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this issue lately and tinkered until I found a solution since Google doesn't supply a `linker:decorator` function anymore.

Using an anchor to grab the `_gl` value didn't work but using a form did work. Although I couldn't make it work with just a form so I also used a button to submit the form. My guess is that GA4 is using some undisclosed heuristics to determine legitimate user interaction before decorating a URL.

```js
 

function getLinkerParameter() {

  //create form element, give it an action, make it hidden and prevent the submit event

  const formNode = document.createElement('FORM');

  formNode.action = '[external URL here, e.g. https://google.com/]';

  formNode.style.opacity = '0';

  formNode.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {event.preventDefault();});

 

  //create a button node, make it type=submit and append it to the form

  const buttonNode = document.createElement('BUTTON');

  buttonNode.type = 'submit';

  formNode.append(buttonNode);

 

  //append the form (and button) to the DOM

  document.body.append(formNode);

 

  //trigger a click on the button node to submit the form

  buttonNode.click();

 

  //check for the input[name=_gl] hidden input in the form (if decoration worked)

  const _glNode = formNode.querySelector('input[name="_gl"]');

  if (_glNode) {

    return _glNode.value;

  }

 

  return '';

}
```

Comment: There are no heuristics, but gtag only listens for `mousedown` on links rather than `click`. So instead of `.click()` you need to call something like `.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }))` on the anchor Element.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't grokked this solution, and I am not sure it answers your question directly, but Simo does give an outline of how to configure GA4 cross domain tracking here:

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/cross-domain-tracking-google-analytics-4/#how-to-configure-cross-domain-tracking-manually

He breaks the problem down into steps but does not go into great detail. He provides one code snippet:

"...you could also load the URL parameter values directly into the GA4 configuration with something like:

```
gtag('config', 'G-12345', {
  // Namespace roll-up trackers
  cookie_prefix: 'roll-up',
  // Pull in the Client ID from the URL
  client_id: (new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)).get('client_id'),
  // Pull in the Session ID from the URL
  session_id: (new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)).get('session_id')  
});
```

"

Hope that helps!

Comment: Add actually another great blogger provides some code for solving some of the steps: https://www.thyngster.com/cross-domain-tracking-on-google-analytics-4-ga4